Performance in Go: Mutex vs RWMutex
There are two types of mutex in Go: Mutex and RWMutex

Mutex offers func Lock() and func Unlock().

RWMutex offers those functions plus func RLock() and func RUnlock().


From what I understand, we should only use RWMutex when there are many read operations and few write operations, to allow for concurrent reads. It also is more time-consuming to write-lock.
But what if I only use RWMutex and alternate using func Lock() / func Unlock() when I want to allow concurrent reads and func RLock / func RUnlock when I want to do the same as a normal Mutex. Is using RLock / RUnlock the same time as a normal mutex equivalent functions?
TLDR: Why use Mutex when RWMutex offers the same functionality with more options?

There is no problem at all from the semantic point of view, except that the semantic of RWMutex-es is slightly more complex, methods may use a little more time to operate.

See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38813

A RWMutex need to care about a lot of problems, for example writers starvation. A Mutex is much simpler and in fact used as a building block for a RWMutex.
So in principle you could just use a RWMutex as a mutex, but then you would use the underlying Mutex with additional - in this case unnecessary - logic on top. Since concurrency is complicated enough, you usually strive to keep everything as simple and performant as possible, therefore using the simplest construct that fits your needs.
